# moments of weight vectors in Adam

Tags: machine-learning, gradient-descent, backpropagation

When performing backpropagation with Adam algorithm, are the moment and the second moment of the weight vectors calculated also for the weights in hidden layers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it.

The equations in the description of the algorithm in [Hands-on Machine Learning](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-machine-learning/9781492032632/) as well as the [original paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.6980) do not differentiate between parameters (weights) in different layers. Further, the [scikit-learn implementation](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/neural_network/_stochastic_optimizers.py#L198) of Adam has `ms` and `vs` (first and second moment) vectors equal to the length of the parameters, and update these alongside updates to the weights themselves.

[Typically](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/9aaed4987/sklearn/neural_network/_multilayer_perceptron.py#L761), the parameters of a multilayer neural network are [unpacked or unrolled into a single vector](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dlEoLfA4MSQ&list=PLLssT5z_DsK-h9vYZkQkYNWcItqhlRJLN&index=53), which is what gets passed into the call to the optimizer function. Since the first and second moments are calculated for all of this vector in the scikit-learn implementation, you are right that the gradients are calculated for the weights in the hidden layers as well.

I hope that helps.